# Cannot activate/turn on Windows Subsystem for Linux feature on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having a really strange issue with turning on the Linux subsystem on Windows 10 and I've scoured the internet to see if anyone has had this issue -- to no avail.

Basically, I click the checkmark for 'Windows Subsystem for Linux' in 'Turn Windows features on or off' and reboot... Except my laptop reboots into repair mode and I have to use a system restore point to even boot the OS correctly. Essentially, my laptop gets bricked if I try to turn on the subsystem.

What I have tried:

- Windows updating
- Turning on with powershell (with admin privileges)

[windows build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi8Mc.png)

Note that this is NOT an issue with installing any of the unix systems. I am having trouble with activating the subsystem on Windows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Sorry if I'm missing any information! I'm rather new to stack. If you guys need anything else, dxdiag/logs I could provide them.

Comment: There are hundreds issues present in [GitHub: WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues) with same problem. The ultimate solution: CLEAN install Windows 10, nothing else.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I was hoping there might be a simpler way to fix it, but I will do this if it is what it takes!

Comment: Also you may upgrade to lates Windows version.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that already. Did not work unfortunately. Some of my windows updates aren't working either, so a clean install could work.

Comment: What is the version of your Windows?